# 'module' object has no attribute 'utilities'

Tags: python

Trying to implement ytini (yt for Houdini) Python framework.
http://www.ytini.com/

Resolved most install erros but am still getting the following when I load a datfile

Not sure if this might be related to some configuration for ytini or if its more of a Python specific error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 14,
  in File "/home/jim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yt/__init__.py", line 44,
    in import yt.utilities.physical_constants as physical_constants
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'utilities
```

Can any Python experts suggest any troubleshooting steps?

Update>

If I simply do an import yt  I get the following error

Warning! ***HDF5 library version mismatched error***
The HDF5 header files used to compile this application do not match
the version used by the HDF5 library to which this application is linked.
Data corruption or segmentation faults may occur if the application continues.
This can happen when an application was compiled by one version of HDF5 but
linked with a different version of static or shared HDF5 library.
You should recompile the application or check your shared library related
settings such as 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'.
'HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK' environment variable is set to 1, application will
continue at your own risk.
Headers are 1.10.0, library is 1.8.11

Comment: can you execute only this line in your python console ? `import yt.utilities.physical_constants as physical_constants`

Comment: Did you name your own file yt.py?

Comment: OP.
No yt.py is previously installed using PIP. 
When I execute in Python console get exact same error.

Comment: OP. When I open the actual yt directory I DO see a folder named utilities. Confused why the error is mentioning 'attribute'? https://imgur.com/a/9BScq8Q

Comment: OP. Is it possible I've mistakenly installed 2 copies of yt in different locations? If so how would I check this?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you are treating yt.utilities as an object from which you are trying to access the object attribute physical constants, which is correct, but python thinks that this attribute doesn't exist. However, I am unable to reproduce this error and can access the values stored therein. What else is in your code? It looks like you are accessing another module function of yt which uses the constants attributes, is that correct? Also, are you using python 2.7 or 3.x?

In terms of installing package in 2 different places, I've had this happen before which was very frustrating, but the folders can be found by doing a folder search for the module name and should return all versions saved in different locations. The exact location of the modules varies with IDE, OS, weather...

Comment: OP. Please see my update. Doing just an import yt gives a HDF5 library version mismatched error. This might be my real error. How might I resolve this?

Comment: OP. Ok so resolved mismatch error by uninstalling yt using PIP uninstall yt then used miniconda to reinstall. Now my problem is that my application can't find the yt package. How do I find the new python path to the miniconda  yt installation?

Comment: You should install packages in the packages folder used by your IDE, each python IDE normally had a process of automating package installation to avoid problems such as this, yt was available from the main repo in pycharm, was this not the case for you?